# Build not publishing Web API project in Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, build, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have created a VS build definition on Team Services. The build runs successfully when I queue it and it also outputs the dlls for all the projects in the solution except the service layer which I have created using Web Api2.

when I download the artifacts from the drop location, I have folders holding the dlls for the data layer, the business layer and other helper projects. What I don't have is the main service layer dll which I can deploy to my IIS.

Here is a screenshot of my publish settings.

[image]

What could I be missing ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that you are using the default settings for the build definition. With these settings, the contents for "Copy Files" task is "**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)**" while web api project does not have buildconfiguration folder. So it cannot find the files for web api project. To copy these files, add one more "Copy Files" task and configure the settings as following:
[image]

If you want the deployment files for the project, you need to set you build definition as following:

1. Add arguments `/p:DeployOnBuild=true;OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"` for `Visual Studio Build` step.
2. Remove `Copy Files` step.
3. Set Path to Publish to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\_PublishedWebsites` for `Publish Build Artifacts` step.

Then you should get the deployment files in the drop folder.

Comment: Thanks. that doesn't seem to copy files like a publish action would. I was expecting the global.asax and the web.config file to be there too along with the bin folder. When I right click the project and use the publish option , it copies all the files required to run the service, namely the bin folder and the global.asax & web.config.

Comment: Also, the copy files step still seems to be copying the dlls from the other projects. I was expecting only the service related files and bin folder to be published. Is there a way I can control that? Later when I add an MVC project what other steps would I need to take?

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But will this solution work if I have multiple service projects and a mvc project in the solution as well ?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT is there a full article for this work? thanks

Answer (score -1):

Open the Configuration Manager in VisualStudio and ensure the WebAPI project is included for the configuration (Debug, Release, etc) that you are building.

[image]